# EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6, ng-build

Sometimes when I try to launch the angular-cli command :

```
ng build --app myApplication -w
```

I get the following error :

```
EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink 'C:\...\inline.bundle.js'
```

Any idea to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had the same problem with `google-services.json` when trying to deploy the app to the device.

`EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink 'C:\...\google-services.json'`

Solution:
Open task manager on windows and kill the `Java(TM) Platform SE Binary`  process in task manager.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer according to votes

Comment: In my case there were 3 processes in task manager -> Details. I had to end all of them

Answer (score 1):

here is a better workaround (bash on windows)

```
# for some reason keep getting UBUSY error so kill process
echo "killing any java.exe tasks"
cmd '/C TASKKILL /f /im java.exe'
```

Comment: The accepted answer works most of the time but this command is also working.